# Django- session cookies and sites on multiple ports

Tags: django, cookies

I have multiple Django projects running on one server using [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/). Currently they are each configured to run on a unique port of the same IP address using the server directive in nginx. All this works fine.

```
...
server {
    listen 81;
    server_name my.ip.x.x;
    ... #static hosting and reverse proxy to site1
}
server {
    listen 84;
    server_name my.ip.x.x;
    ... #static hosting and reverse proxy to site2
}
...
```

I came across a problem when I had 2 different projects open in 2 tabs and I realized that I could not be logged into both sites at once (both use the built-in Django User model and auth). Upon inspecting the cookies saved in my browser, I realized that the cookie is bound to just the domain name (in my case just an ip address) and it does not include the port.

On the second site, I tried changing [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) annd [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain), but it doesn't seem to be working and with these current settings I can't even log in.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'my.ip.x.x:84'  #solution is to leave this as default
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'site2'           #just using this works 
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'               #solution is to leave this as default

#site1 is using all default values for these
```

What do I need to do to get cookies for both sites working independently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just change the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`. The `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` doesn't support port numbers afaik. So they are all the same for your apps.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. And it wasn't working. But of course, after you recommend it and I try it again it works... Thanks! Also, I think this problem would have fixed itself once we get the internal DNS setup (all these sites are internal use apps).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that doesn't require hard-coding different cookie names for each site is to write a middleware that changes the cookie name based on the port the request came in on.

[Here's a simple version](https://gist.github.com/turtlemonvh/48d92d4153754aea4504) (just a few lines of code).