# Django Admin Error (Always require login couple of time) when DEBUG = False (Productions)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, session, django-admin, django-settings

I've just deployed Django 2.2 in Google App Engine.

Everything works fine except this one.
The admin page requires login couple of time till I can finally go to the dashboard.
This happens also when I click on the Post model to create a new post, I need to login again.
I'm not sure why but this happen when the `DEBUG = False`.

I take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176587/django-admin-asks-for-login-after-every-click) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42102374/9105008) but it might bit different for the debug.

Does anyone have the same issue as mine?

Here's my `settings.py` file:

```
DEBUG = False
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!


BASE_URL = "https://example.com"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
#     'www.notnoob.com',
#     'notnoob.com'
# ]


# SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
# SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'home',
    'blog',                                                                 
    'contact',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'taggit',
    'meta',
    'django_filters',

]

...
...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dj/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dj.wsgi.application'

.....
.....

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = 'cloudsql/djangoblogdb'
if os.getenv('GAE_INSTANCE'):
    pass
else:
    DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = 'localhost'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Not sure why but when the `DEBUG = True`, everything goes well.

My `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post, MetaModel

admin.site.site_header = "Welcome To iColdPlayer"
admin.site.site_title = "iColdPlayer Administrator"
admin.site.site_index = "iColdPlayer"

# site = admin.AdminSite(name="iColdPlayer")

# class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#     pass
#
# class MetaModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#     pass

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(MetaModel)
```

**Edit**: I'm using *Flexible Environment*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing your data in SQLITE3, and probably you have more than one GAE running.

So you login on Instance 1, but is redirected to Instance 2 (stateless.....)

And guess what, on 2, you are not logged in, so you have to do it again.

To fix, change your `app.yml` to set maximum instances to 1 or use a mysql outside GAE to store your sessions....

Let me know if that solves it

Comment: I wonder if you mean is a storage bucket. Cause I have only one instance in it.

Comment: send a screenshot of your running instance (on the Google dashboard), and your app.yml please

Comment: Here's the screenshot: 

- [instance running](https://i.imgur.com/FOyGmvp.jpg)

- [app.yaml](https://i.imgur.com/sd551V7.jpg)

- [Storage Bucket](https://i.imgur.com/dxpJhVH.jpg)

Comment: on your app yaml, define the max number of instances to 1... and are u or are u not using the postgree? b/c your settings says SQLITE

Comment: well, I think it makes sense for the different databases. Cause I thought it was like on heroku that we're able to use different databases when in deployment.
Already change my `settings.py` under `beta_settings: instances: 1`  but not yet for the `db`. I am still curious about it...

Comment: on your settings there is a reference to using a DB, but I didnt see the other required details

Comment: solved by inserting:

`manual_scaling: instances: 1` in `app.yaml` as you suggested. Thanks a lot!.

it says also from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)

Comment: Ah, I will. But my reputations still too low. noobish here. xD